# use of --output-fd parameter in dialog utility

Tags: linux, bash, redirect, dialog, stdout

I'm working on an embedded linux system; my console is a serial port and there is a VGA video output at /dev/tty0.

I am trying to use the 'dialog' (1) utility to display menu-like displays on the VGA screen.

I can get dialog output on the console:

```
dialog --inputbox "Hello Dialog World" 10 30
```

and I can get something similar on the VGA screen by redirection:

```
dialog --inputbox "Hello Dialog World" 10 30 >/dev/tty0
```

But I want to use the '`--output-fd`' parameter to dialog to achieve a similar result and I can't get it to work.

I've tried things in a bash script like:

```
exec 4>/dev/tty0
dialog --output-fd 4 --inputbox "Hello Dialog World" 10 30
exec 4>&-
```

but this seems to write to the console as previously.

I seem to be misunderstanding the operation of the `--output-fd` parameter - can anyone help?

(in actual fact, I want to use the python-dialog wrapper for dialog; but I need to understand how to use the underlying dialog utility before I take the next step)

Answer (score 0):

Quote from the manual page:

> Some widgets, e.g., checklist, will write text to dialog’s output. 
>   Normally that is the standard error, but there are options for
>   changing this:  "--out-put-fd", "--stderr" and "--stdout".

This means that the `--output-fd` option does not specify a file descriptor for any output but only for the data generated by some widgets.